# DurandalJS View binding to Kendo DataSource is not working

Tags: binding, kendo-ui, datasource, durandal

In DurandalJS I've got a View with a form. I would like to fill this form by binding it to a Kendo DataSource.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/durandaljs/6cAxVD3iDj4  Solved in here, maybe it helps to you too.

Answer (score 1):

DataSource is used to bind collection of objects, not a complex object. Better have a look at the [MVVM](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/mvvm/index.html) demo.